# checking if an SKNode is running a SKAction

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction

How can I check whether a `SKNode` is already running an action before running an action on it?
I want to be able to do something like...

```
if (![mySprite isRunningActions]) {
    [mySprite runAction:action]; 
}
```

If there is no built in way I'm thinking of creating a new `BOOL` property for holding the action state.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at using named actions using any of the `SKAction` key-based methods. So you would instead run your action using the named equivalent to `runAction:` which is `runAction:withKey:`. If an action with the same key is already running, it is removed before the new one is added. Alternatively, use `actionForKey:` to see if an action is already running like you are trying to do now in your code, then `removeActionForKey:` to remove it or handle as needed.

Comment: This is a better answer, as you can check for a specific action, rather than checking if the sprite is running any action (of course, that is if you know the key for the action :)

Answer (score 16):

Sorry for the late answer, but you can use the sprite method hasActions to check if a sprite is currently running any actions.

```
if (![mySprite hasActions])
{
   [mySprite runAction:action];
}
```